# Conversion of any base to any base (2-16) going wrong

Tags: c++

Converting a number from any base to any other base:
[UVA 355](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=5&page=show_problem&problem=291).

I have done it in 2 parts: first converting the number in decimal, then converting the decimal number to the desired base.
But in this code below, in the 1st part, sometimes the answer is given wrong, like the sum is less than the real sum in the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int check(long long int f[],long long int b,long long int l);


int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
       long long int i,j,k,l,b1,b2,n,m,f[20],x=0,f1[20],sum=0,ans[20];
       char a[20];

    cin>>b1>>b2;
    if(b1<10) //int input
    {
        cin>>n;
        m=n;
        i=0;
        while(m!=0)
        {
            f1[i]=m%10;
            m=m/10;
            i++;
        }
        i--;
        k=i;
        for(j=0;k>=0;k--,j++)
        {
            f[j]=f1[k];
        }
    //check
        long long int chk;
        chk=check(f,b1,i);
        if(chk==1)
            {
                printf("%lld is an illegal base %lld number\n",n,b1);
                x=1;
            }
    }
    else
    {
        cin>>a; //char input

        for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
            if(a[i]=='A')
                f[i]=10;
            else if(a[i]=='B')
                f[i]=11;
            else if(a[i]=='C')
                f[i]=12;
            else if(a[i]=='D')
                f[i]=13;
            else if(a[i]=='E')
                f[i]=14;
            else if(a[i]=='F')
                f[i]=15;
            else
                f[i]=a[i]-'0';

        }
        i--;
//check
        long long int chk;
        chk=check(f,b1,i);
        if(chk==1)
            {
                printf("%s is an illegal base %lld number\n",a,b1);
                x=1;
            }
    }
    //convert to dec

if(x==0)
{

 for(k=i,j=0;k>=0;j++,k--)
 {
     sum=sum+(f[j]*pow(b1,k)); //shows sum=sum-1 sometimes
 }

}
//convert dec to desired base

j=0;
while(sum!=0)
{
    ans[j]=sum%b2;

    sum=sum/b2;
    j++;

}
j--;
char c[20]={};
for(k=0;j>=0;j--,k++)
{
    if(ans[j]==10)
        c[k]='A';
    else if(ans[j]==11)
        c[k]='B';
    else if(ans[j]==12)
        c[k]='C';
        else if(ans[j]==13)
        c[k]='D';
        else if(ans[j]==14)
        c[k]='E';
        else if(ans[j]==15)
        c[k]='F';
        else
        c[k]=ans[j]+'0';
}
cout<<c;
}

    return 0;
}


 //check validity
int check(long long int f[],long long int b,long long int l)
{
     int chk=0,j;
    for(j=0;j<=l;j++)
    {
        if(f[j]>=b)
            chk=1;

    }
    return chk;
}
```

input style: (given_base) (desired_base) (number).....

```
ex:  in: 10 10 100
output 99 (should be 100)
```

From the UVA site:

> Sample input
>
> ```
> 2 10 10101
> 5 3 126
> 15 11 A4C
> ```
>
> Sample output
>
> ```
> 10101 base 2 = 21 base 10 
> 126 is an illegal base 5 number 
> A4C base 15 = 1821 base 11
> ```

Comment: Can you please give us an example, for some input what is the actual and expected output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg He already provided that. `input style: (given_base) (desired_base) (number)..... ex: in: 10 10 100 output 99 (should be 100)`

Comment: Why two parts? You don't need that. The code is identical in both parts except for the constants. No need to write it all twice.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason not to use `strtoll()` or `strtoull()` for the input conversion?  The input digit string can be up to 10 digits in the base, so they easily fit into a `long long` type, even in base-16 (but 10 base-16 digits would overflow a 32-bit `long`).  There isn't a standard  'print in specifiable base' function (at least, not in the C library; there might be in C++), but it isn't dreadfully hard to write (though it is often gotten wrong).  Surely you need a table of 'digits' — `const char *digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";` and can use that to encode in the given base.

Comment: Using floating point function `pow()` in the conversion loop `for(k=i,j=0;k>=0;j++,k--)
 {
     sum=sum+(f[j]*pow(b1,k)); }` is not entirely sensible. There are better ways to compute the value than this, at any rate.

Comment: You're guessing. I suggest you look up how to do this. You can do it in a single step with two nested loops in about ten lines of code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *Now* there is, check the edit history.

Comment: i m jst a beginner..do the very basic C codes ..trying to improve ..bt  thnx everyone for helping me ...

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine when I have run your code. But if you are facing any problem then it should be because of th built in pow function. You have to write your own pow function or you can ceil the value of the power function.

I have been using this function:

```
long long POW(long long b, long long p)
{
     if(p == 0LL)
         return 1LL;
     long long t = POW(b, p >> 1);
         return p & 1LL ? t * t * b : t * t;
}
```